# How to implements batch-processing in zendframework

Tags: batch-processing, zend-framework3

I'm about to write a batch-processing Controller for my zendframework 3.0 applications. But I hope I wont recreate the well.

I did some search at GitHub's Zendframework repositories but found nothing.

Does somebody know if a zend batch-processing controller exists and how to get it?

Thanks in advance.

Luis

Comment: what is "batch-processing"?

Comment: I think you want to create a console controller. Look this up.

Comment: Not exactly. There are a lot of admin-tasks involving batch-processing you wanna do on-line. that's what i need.

Comment: Hi @tasmaniski. Sorry for not responding your question. There is a good article on batch-processing at wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing)